# How can I resolve the error when importing pandas_profiling for BigMart sales prediction project?

Tags: python, pandas-profiling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRQOM.png)
I am getting error in importing pandas_profiling. pls help  me to resolve this problem.

Actually I am doing my college project BigMart Sales prediction for that I needed some library like klib,dtale,pandas_profiling for eda but when I importing panadas_profiling  I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1 - install ydata-profiling (previously called pandas-profiling)

pip install ydata_profiling

import ydata_profiling

2 - since it's a college project, use their community version which will save you a lot of work:
https://ydata.ai/ydata-fabric-free-trial